# How can I prevent the keyboard in PhoneGap from hiding?

Tags: cordova, keyboard

I have a text field and a button. When the user enters text and hits the button currently by default the keyboard slides down (hides).

I want the keyboard to stay up and not go down because the user should be able to enter most text in the text field and hit send again. I don't want the keyboard to go up and down.

How can I change the default behavior of the keyboard in PhoneGap 2.0.0?

Comment: any luck? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to show / hide the keyboard from javascript on any platform by focusing / blurring on your text input element, i.e [ Assuming jQuery]:

```
 // To focus on your input and show the keyboard
 $('input#my_input_id').focus();

  // To blur on your input and hide the keyboard
  $('input#my_input_id').blur();
```

This is what I tried in my phonegap build [ Android app] and works for me.

Comment: This doesn't allow preventing of keyboard close.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the keyboard always shown and tell the user to close it when the actions are done.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

inputManager.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

Try this code in the onCreate() method of your Activity.If the user presses the close button on the keyboard or the back button it would close it.When these actions are done you can then close the keyboard from code.

Comment: Where would I put this code in an phonegap application?